# Cannot GET //__ion-dev-server/ionic_lab.html in ionic 2.1.8

Tags: cordova, typescript, ionic2

I have updated my local setup such as-

- ionic
- cordova
- npm
  See the system environment available on my machine-

---

```
******************************************************

Your system information:

Cordova CLI: 6.4.0 
Ionic Framework Version: 2.0.0-rc.2
Ionic CLI Version: 2.1.8
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.1.4
Ionic App Scripts Version: 0.0.43
ios-deploy version: Not installed
ios-sim version: 5.0.8 
OS: OS X Yosemite
Node Version: v6.2.2
Xcode version: Xcode 7.2 Build version 7C68



******************************************************
```

after that I run the server by typing-

> ionic start

It works but display only one view on browser instead of three (android, ios & windows).
When I use different command to get that all as-

> ionic serve --lab (or) ionic serve -l

It just shows error on browser as-

> Cannot GET //__ion-dev-server/ionic_lab.html

I got some questions [there in ionic forum](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-serve-lab-dont-work-in-rc2/69862) but that won't work for me as there was no answer of that.

Hope for help!!!

Comment: I have same issue, did you find any solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I changed Package.json to

`"scripts": {
    "ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build"
},`

The `ionic serve --lab` will serve, but it will not watch (auto-update when changes are made)

Then I found this solution: [Ionic serve –lab don’t work in RC2](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-serve-lab-dont-work-in-rc2/69862/7)

I changed Package.json to

`"scripts": {
  "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
  "watch": "ionic-app-scripts watch",
  "serve:before": "watch",
  "emulate:before": "watch",
  "deploy:before": "build",
  "build:before": "build",
  "run:before": "watch"
},`

And `ionic serve --lab` is now watching(auto-update when changes are made)

Answer (score 4):

Package.json  and remove "ionic:serve"

```
"scripts": {
    "ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve"
},
```

Remove "ionic:serve"

```
"scripts": {
    "ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build"
},
```

Comment: Please look at [answer]

Comment: It worked for me, thanks.
I just added 
"scripts": {
    "ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build"
},

instead of above code.

Answer (score 1):

> Hi @Gulab Chand & @Vojtech Ruzicka,

I am really happy and thankful for your great support.
This is what I did-

1. Opened package.json of the application-
2. Just removed-

---

```
"scripts": {
    "ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve"
},
```

3. and added-

---

```
"scripts": {
    "ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build"
},
```

This worked for me!
Now ionic serve -l -c -s / ionic serve --lab working fine which resultant is here-
[image]

Answer (score 0):

try `npm install --save-dev @ionic/app-scripts@latest` 
cehck [ionic-cli-issue](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-cli/issues/1666#issuecomment-260714389)